# How to know if the next chunk in a Firestore pagination is empty?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I have created a pagination algorithm for a Firestore collection. The limit of elements displayed is 5. If I have 12 items in my collection, 3 pages will be displayed. I have a condition where I check to see if the size of the last `QueryDocumentSnapshot` object is less than my limit, so I cannot continue. In this example, 2 < 5, the pagination stops.

However, if we have for instance 15 elements, my algorithm displays 3 pages but it is also looking for the 4'th page. As the size it will be 0, the pagination stops. How can I avoid this extra step? Is there any way I can know in advance, that the next chuck of documents is empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To know whether there is a next page, you'll typically load one extra item for each page. So if you're displaying 5 items per page, you'd try to load **6** items for the last page. If you get that sixth item, you know you need to display a <kbd>next page</kbd> link.

Comment: Thank you Frank. So you say I should modify the value in the limit function to `.limit(6)` and in the UI to display only 5? And at the last page if I get exactly 5, just stop the pagination, right?